# Filter Duplicate Like urls from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Working on ES 6.4.2. How can I filter the below results.

```
Title: Some TITLE
Description:A Storm application is designed as a "topology" in the shape of a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with spouts and bolts acting as the graph vertices. Edges on the graph are named streams and direct data from one node to another. Together, the topology acts as a data transformation pipeline. At a superficial level the general topology structure is similar to a MapReduce job, with the main difference being that data is processed in real time as opposed to in individual batches. Additionally, Storm topologies run indefinitely until killed, while a MapReduce job DAG must eventually end.
url: https://www.someurl.com


Title: Some TITLE 
Description:A Storm application is designed as a "topology" in the shape of a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with spouts and bolts acting as the graph vertices. Edges on the graph are named streams and direct data from one node to another. Together, the topology acts as a data transformation pipeline. At a superficial level the general topology structure is similar to a MapReduce job, with the main difference being that data is processed in real time as opposed to in individual batches. Additionally, Storm topologies run indefinitely until killed, while a MapReduce job DAG must eventually end.
url: http://www.someurl.com
```

How can I get either one of the record. Title and content is same url and the only one is need to filter http and https. Any Solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple solutions to this, the simplest i can think of is that you use a match phrase query to filter your results. The two query terms in your case would be

> http: and https:

notice that I have deliberately used colon after the http so that the https phrase doesn't match.

here is your query

```
GET yourIndexName/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "url": "http:"
    }
  }
}

GET yourIndexname/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "url": "https:"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I use either one of the query it gives only https or http records. My index also some unique urls starts with http and https how the query will work here. If I use the http match phrase the https urls will miss right.

Comment: in your question you have stated : "How can I get either one of the record.", the above answer solves that problem. So if you need both http and https then just put "url":"http" in match phrase query, if you need conditions like "or" "And" as per your business logic then wrap the entire thing up in a bool query